# AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release

Tags: https

AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:571

I am using Centos6 Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  4 2015 01:21:07

***file contact of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf***

570 NameVirtualHost 104.238.119.91 :80
571 NameVirtualHost 104.238.119.91:80

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem setting up a new virtual server with CentOS 7 and httpd 2.4.6 (installed via yum).
My httpd logged in the correct file, so I was sure the VirtualHost directive was OK, but still got a 403 error.
Actually, the directive  has been dropped after httpd 2.3.11.
Now these lines should suffice:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName Your-server-name here
  DocumentRoot /your/path/
</VirtualHost>
```

If for some reason you are still seeing the test page, keep on reading.
When I added *these* lines to the VirtualHost everything worked as expected:

```
<Directory /your/path>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just add `<VirtualHost...><Directory "..."></Directory></VirtualHost>` and it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks I tried but didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I just found a solution to make it work on Ubuntu 14.04, basically you just add those `<Directory></Directory>` as in your answer but for some reasons you need to enable it with `sudo a2ensite domain.com.conf` too. See here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts.